# What should the primary key be when there is multiple relations?

Tags: sql, postgresql, model, entity, relation

[image]

I am trying to create a table for the member relation, however I am unsure how to create this given that there are 2 of them with different entities. Would the primary key be (group, user) or(friends, person)

Comment: They're two different membership tables.  You're thinking of them as one only because your picture doesn't name them explicitly enough.  The table names should describe what is a member of what.  For examples `group_user_membership` or `link_group_user`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Consider reading the following article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask